# Some Problem with Some ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Please could some kind person help me out here. My aspx page comtain following:

In the Content panel of the one page I have placed 3 AccordionPanes. In this I placed 3 gridview controls. The idea is that when I select one of the rows in the Gridview in Pane 1 or Pane 2  the row should be added to third gridview.
..I hope that makes sense.

When I link the Gridview  in a normal page (not using the Accordion control) it works

Comment: Please include samples of markup and code.  It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do from your description.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the accordion control's controls collection to access the 3rd grid view, as an accordion is a control container.